# Get custom property field's attributes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My my example below I've created an attribute called 'filters'. How can i get the attributes values using jquery? which would be **games**, **vfx**, **video**?

```
<div class="portfolio-item" filters="games vfx video">
     <p>This is a test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: And you've created an invalid attribute, it should have been a data-attribute

Comment: could you show an example of how to do that?

Comment: <div class="portfolio-item" data-filters="games vfx video">. Though i don't think filters is an invalid attribute. It's just another property of the div object, though user-defined.

Comment: @DinoMyte: You mean `data-filters="games vfx video"`

Comment: `<div class="portfolio-item" data-filters="games vfx video">`

Comment: @squint: Yup. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: And with jQuery, you can even make it an array -> https://jsfiddle.net/s51sayvc/

Comment: @adeneo how can i test if a string is in the returned array of filters then?

Comment: `if ( arr.indexOf(str) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do :

```
$('.portfolio-item') // use class selector to target the class 'portfolio-item'
.attr('filters'); // This would give you the value of the attribute 'filters'
```

As pointed by others, you should use `data attributes` ( as supported by jquery 1.10 or higher ) for consistency with custom attributes:

```
<div class="portfolio-item" data-filters="games vfx video">
```

and extract its value : `$('.portfolio-item').data('filters');`